# How can I check if a value is changed on blur event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onblur

Basically I need to check if the value is changed in a textbox on the 'blur' event so that if the value is not changed, I want to cancel the blur event.

If it possible to check it the value is changed by user on the blur event of an input HTML element?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't think there is a native way to do this. What I would do is, add a function to the `focus` event that saves the current value into a variable attached to the element (`element.oldValue = element.value`). You could check against that value onBLur.

Comment: Good one with out hidden fields ;)

Comment: Dont know why this is the excepted answer, this can be done, as in answers below https://stackoverflow.com/a/40666726/3043793

Comment: @arecaps That only works if there wasn't a value in the input to begin with.

Answer (score 8):

Within the `onblur` event, you can compare the `value` against the `defaultValue` to determine whether a change happened:

```html
<input onblur="if(this.value!=this.defaultValue){alert('changed');}">
```

The `defaultValue` will contain the **initial** value of the object, whereas the `value` will contain the **current** value of the object *after a change has been made*.

References:

[value vs defaultValue](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnqsrfe.php)

Comment: In this case every current value will be different from defaultValue. Should not work fine

Comment: This approach works only once. On the second change the value would be compared to what was in the field in the very beginning, not to what was in the field immediately before the change.

Answer (score 6):

You can't cancel the blur event, you need to refocus in a timer.  You could either set up a variable onfocus or set a `hasChanged` variable on the change event.  The blur event fires after the change event (unfortunately, for this situation) otherwise you could have just reset the timer in the onchange event.

I'd take an approach similar to this:

```
(function () {
    var hasChanged;
    var element = document.getElementById("myInputElement");
    element.onchange = function () { hasChanged = true; }
    element.onblur = function () {
        if (hasChanged) {
            alert("You need to change the value");

            // blur event can't actually be cancelled so refocus using a timer
            window.setTimeout(function () { element.focus(); }, 0);          
        }
        hasChanged = false;
    }
})();
```

Comment: "you can't cancel a blur event". 
I think he means something like "if (!hasChanged) return false;"

Answer (score 5):

Why not just maintaining a custom flag on the input element?

```
input.addEventListener('change', () => input.hasChanged = true);
input.addEventListener('blur', () => 
{
    if (!input.hasChanged) { return; }
    input.hasChanged = false;
    // Do your stuff
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d7yx63aj

Comment: Simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery events we can do this logic

Step1 : Declare a variable to compare the value

```
var  lastVal ="";
```

Step 2: On focus get the last value from form input

```
  $("#validation-form :input").focus(function () {
                 lastVal = $(this).val();

  });
```

Step3:On blur compare it

```
$("#validation-form :input").blur(function () {
                 if (lastVal != $(this).val())
                 alert("changed");
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
var Old_Val;
var Input_Field = $('#input');

Input_Field.focus(function(){
     Old_Val = Input_Field.val();
});

Input_Field.blur(function(){
    var new_input_val = Input_Field.val();
    if (new_input_val != Old_Val){
          // execute you code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I figured I'd put this in case anyone wants an alternative.  This seems ugly (at least to me) but having to deal with the way the browser handles the -1 index is what was the challenge.  Yes, I know it can be done better with the jquery.data, but I'm not that familiar with that just yet.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<select id="selected">
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
var currentIndex; // set up a global variable for current value

$('#selected').on(
  { "focus": function() { // when the select is clicked on
      currentIndex = $('#selected').val(); // grab the current selected option and store it
      $('#selected').val(-1); // set the select to nothing 
    }
  , "change": function() { // when the select is changed
      choice = $('#selected').val(); // grab what (if anything) was selected
      this.blur(); // take focus away from the select
      //alert(currentIndex);
      //setTimeout(function() { alert(choice); }, 0);
    }
  , "blur": function() { // when the focus is taken from the select (handles when something is changed or not)
      //alert(currentIndex);
      //alert($('#selected').val());
      if ($('#selected').val() == null) { // if nothing has changed (because it is still set to the -1 value, or null)
        $('#selected').val(currentIndex); // set the value back to what it originally was (otherwise it will stay at what was newly selected)
      } else { // if anything has changed, even if it's the same one as before
        if ($('#selected').val() == 2) { // in case you want to do something when a certain option is selected (in my case, option B, or value 2) 
            alert('I would do something');
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Using Kevin Nadsady's above suggestion of

> this.value!=this.defaultValue

I use a shared CSS class on a bunch of inputs then do:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < myInputs.length; i++) {
        myInputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function (evt) {
            if(this.value!=this.defaultValue){
                //value was changed now do your thing
            }
        });
        myInputs[i].addEventListener('focus', function (evt) {
            evt.target.setAttribute("value",evt.target.value);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is an old post, I thought i'd share a way to do this with simple javascript.

The javascript portion:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideLabel(txtField){
     if(txtField.name=='YOURBOXNAME'){
         if(txtField.value=='YOURBOXNAME')
             txtField.value = '';
         else
             txtField.select();
         
     }
 }
 function ShowLabel(YOURBOXNAME){
     if(txtField.name=='YOURBOXNAME'){
         if(txtField.value.trim()=='')
             txtField.value = 'YOURDEFAULTVALUE';
     }
 }
</script>
```

Now the text field in your form:

```html
<input type="text" id="input" name="YOURBOXNAME" value="1" onfocus="HideLabel(this)" 
onblur="ShowLabel(this)">
```

And bewn! No Jquery needed. just simple javascript. cut and paste those bad boys. (remember to put your javascript above the body in your html)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Kevin Nadsady's post, the following will work in native JS functions and JQuery listener events. Within the onblur event, you can compare the value against the defaultValue:

```
 $(".saveOnChange").on("blur", function () {
     if (this.value != this.defaultValue) {
         //Set the default value to the new value
         this.defaultValue = this.value;
         //todo: save changes
         alert("changed");
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a hidden field to keep the old value and whenever the onblur event happens, check the change and update the hidden value with the current text value

```
string html = "<input type=text id=it" + row["cod"] + "inputDesc value='"
                    + row["desc"] + "' onblur =\"if (this.value != document.getElementById('hd" + row["cod"].ToString() + 
                    "inputHiddenDesc').value){ alert('value change'); document.getElementById('hd" + row["cod"].ToString() + 
                    "inputHiddenDesc').value = this.value; }\"> " +
                    "<input type=hidden id=hd" + row["cod"].ToString() + "inputHiddenDesc value='" + row["desc"] + "'>";
```